# Custom Error Page with CloudFront and ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have an Application Load Balancer (ALB) on AWS, which contains Rules to forward requests to my private EC2 instances. Whenever I perform a new deployment, I use a Lambda script to temporarily turn off my Auto Scaling Groups (ASGs) and then turn them back on. During this deployment process, when the ASGs are down, the ALB responds with the default 503 error. I want to display a custom error page from a separate S3 bucket instead.

Here's what I did:

Created a CloudFront distribution with the Origin set to the ALB URL and set the Default (*) behavior to the ALB, using a CNAME: *.mywebsite.com.

Created an S3 bucket, uploaded my custom error page HTML under /error/index.html, and set it up as a static hosted website.

Added a new Origin in the existing CloudFront distribution, with the origin set to the static hosted S3 website URL.

Added a new Behavior with a Path Pattern of /error/index.html, associating it with the S3 Origin.

Added a new Error Page rule with HTTP Error Code 503, Page Response Path /error/index.html, and HTTP Response Code 403 (I know 403 is wrong for this case, but I wanted to test if it would change the response code at least, but it did not).

However, when I try to access my website while the EC2 instances are down, I still get the same default 503 error page (which I think comes from the ALB, right?).

Regarding steps 2) and 3), I also tried using the S3 Origin instead of the Custom Origin, but it still didn't work.

By the way, when I access the xxx.cloudfront.net URL of the distribution, I get my custom error page with a 200 OK response (is this correct?).

What am I doing wrong?